# Is there a way to get “arp” to list devices on all subnets of a network?

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, arp

I'm using `arp -an` on Mac OS X to list all devices on my network, but (as I understand it) this just lists devices on the same subnet. Is it possible to list *all* devices on the network and not just my computer’s subnet?

I don’t know if this is possible with the `arp` command, or if I can automatically switch subnets and run `arp`?

Comment: The ARP table only contains devices your computer has talked to. In most cases, this is not a complete list of all devices in your subnet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ARP will only list address that are on the same subnet as your computer.

To do what you want you might want to use `nmap` to check all computers that are connected to a certain network.

Or If all your devices are configured via DHCP—yes, DHCP can serve multiple subnets, depending on the DHCP server that is being used—you might check the DHCP leases file.

Edit as requested:

```
nmap -n -sn 10.0.0.0/24
```

or

```
nmap -n -sP 10.0.0.0/24
```

depending wich version of nmap you have (-sn is for newer versions).

replace the 10.0.0.0/25 for each subnet you have.

Comment: Thanks – `nmap` looks really complicated. What would the command be to list computers on the network?

Comment: The -n is to avoid doing dns lookups on the ips.

Comment: believe is correct now.

Comment: Thanks for the update! I'm feeling dumb though – would I iterate every IP address with `/` and the number of each possible subnet? If I get the response `30 hosts up` does that mean there are 30 devices on that subnet?

Answer (score 2):

From your system, there will not be a way to do so. That could be done from the router that's housing said subnets. Your computer will never be aware that it is even a part of a subnet, if there is one. Therefore, your show ARP will only show information within your subnet.

Answer (score 1):

Your computer only needs to track ARP entries for computers on the same subnet.  For all other computers, it goes through a router to get there.  The router stores arp entries for all devices that it knows about.  That being said, if your computer is connected to multiple subnets (usually by using multiple NICs or multiple VLANs one one NIC) , then it will have ARP entries for *all* networks that it is connected to.

If you don't really have to have the MAC addresses, then use some other tool that is based on the IP address instead.  If you have access to query your main router with SNMP tools, then you can gain a wealth of information.  If you only know your IP ranges, then you can write a simple loop script or use a network scanner to ping each address.  As mentioned by others, nmap is an excellent tool for doing this.

If you do need the MAC address for device outside of your subnet, there may be tricks to do this for some types of devices.  For example, on a Windows network, you can use Windows' `nbtstat -a hostname` to return NetBIOS information on a particular workstation that has NetBIOS enabled.  I'm not sure what all is available in the OS X world.  For some printers, you can query their config pages.